# IIS URL Rewrite from one domain to a different domain with Exact Match

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, exact-match

I want to set up URL rewrite on IIS so when

**https://oldurl.abc.com/portal/apps/#/myapp**

was hit, it will redirect to

**https://newurl.abc.com/myapp**

I have tried the following, but it didn't work. any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: thank @Lex Li for your response. I made the change but still not redirecting - please see above screen shot.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules Let FRT guide you further.

Answer (score 1):

Hash Tags in the URL serve a special purpose to the client browser, not to the server. That means that a browser will NOT actually send anything after a '#' character to the server. So: if you request http://someurl.com/index.aspx#something, the server only sees http://someurl.com/index.aspx.

You could try to use the below rule to resolve the issue:

```
 <rule name="old to new redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldurl.abc.com$" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/portal/apps/(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://newurl.abc.com/myapp" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jalpa. we do have apps like https://oldurl.abc.com/portal/apps/#/OTHERAPPS.  Will your solution also redirect them to https://newurl.abc.com/myapp?

Comment: @AlexW. yes it will redirect anything after /portal/apps/ to https://newurl.abc.com/myapp. one change instead of the (.*) in condition "{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/portal/apps/(.*)" use (.+)

Comment: we only want to redirect a certain app (identified by the name after the #), but it seems not possible with IIS url rewriting. but thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @AlexW. yes, your understanding is right it is not possible in iis. the other workaround is you have to change the folder name which has a special character like # after that you can grab the particular app name and redirect that to a new site.